# No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'UTF8String'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So i'm new to obj-C and Xcode.

I'm making my first small app , i followed some tutorials on the interwebs and tried to make a connection to the db but now i have an error

> No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector
>   'UTF8String'

this appears at the code :  `const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];`

This code was working in another project i made, but when i tried to use it in my definitif project , i get the error.
Can the error be caused because i use storyboards ?

Comment: The problem is that `databasePath` is being declared as a NSMutableArray, and not a NSString. The question is, why?

Comment: Apart from this error, the correct method to convert a string to a file system-specific representation is `fileSystemRepresentation`, not `UTF8String`.

Comment: as @RichardJ.RossIII said, i changed the declaration of databasePath to an NSString and it's working now. For some reason i managed to make it work as an NSMutableArray, but don't know how or why :P (thanks btw :) )

Comment: @Michael: If the object is actually an NSString, then declaring it as NSMutableArray was always wrong and I'd be surprised if this is the only warning you got about the problem. If it is actually an NSMutableArray, then declaring it as NSString is wrong and covers up the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the

`const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];`

The `databasePath` is not an `NSString` it is an `NSArray`

You can check by logging `databasePath`. If you want to extract some strings from it, you can use `databasePath[index]` or `[databasePath objectAtIndex:index]`

Comment: Assuming that it is actually an array and the questioner didn't put a string into that variable.

Comment: @PeterHosey:The error says in this line `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'UTF8String'`

Comment: Yes, that's in the question title. That's irrelevant: It tells you only the type of the variable, not the type of the object that the questioner put into it. If the variable is typed as some kind of array, then array accesses will pass muster with the compiler, but if the object in the variable is not actually an array, then any array access will cause a crash at run time.

Comment: @PeterHosey: Agreed. From given little information I tried to figure out the issue. that is why I said,  check by logging and if it is array extract its objct. But some one upvoted and the OP is no more interested here...

Comment: As i said, by using the same code in another project, I had it working . i changed it to NSString now and it's working ,sorry for my noobishness and thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Michael: So instead of NSString you took NSArray?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Instead of declaring databasePath as an array , I changed it to NSString.